# knex.js - migration fails for dynamic schema name

Tags: node.js, knex.js, ava

## Environment

- Knex version: knex@0.16.3
- Database + version: MySQL 5.7.24
- OS: Linux (Manjaro)

## Bug

I'm trying to setup an integration test suite using [`ava`](https://github.com/avajs/ava). As known, `ava` spawns different Node processes for each test file.

In order to make the tests isolated, I need to re-create my database and run the migrations in all test files. I started bootstrapping and got the following script:

```js
import test from 'ava';
import cuid from 'cuid';
import knexFactory from 'knex';
import knexFile from './knexfile';

const knex = knexFactory(knexFile.development);

test.before(async t => {
  const schemaName = `foo_${cuid()}`;

  await knex.raw(`CREATE SCHEMA ${schemaName}`);

  try {
    await knex.migrate.latest({ schemaName });;
  } catch (err) {

  }

  Object.assign(t.context, { schemaName });
});

test.after.always(async t => {
  const { schemaName } = t.context;
  await knex.raw(`DROP SCHEMA ${schemaName}`);
});

test('foo', () => {})
```

However, I'm running into the following error:

> migration file "20190205110315_create_users_table.js" failed
>   migration failed with error: create table `users` (`id` int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, `email` varchar(255), `password` text) - Table 'users' already exists

What is happening is that the `.migrate.latest()` call is ignoring its `schemaName` parameter and it's running against the configuration defined in the `knexfile.js` file, that is, the actual database.

The migration file is pretty straightforward:

```js
exports.up = function(knex, Promise) {
  return knex.schema.createTable('users', table => {
    table.increments();
    table.string('email');
    table.text('password');
  })
};

exports.down = function(knex, Promise) {
  return knex.schema.dropTable('users');
};
```

Comment: could you share your knexfile.js ?